# .NET CORE | Complex Object cannot pass to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to wrap data forms to an object like this
[image: Wrapped Form Data]

this is my object in mvc;

Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public Biodata? Biodata { get; set; }
    public EmergencyContactPerson? EmergencyContactPerson { get; set; }
}
```

Biodata

```
public class Biodata
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

EmergecnyContactPerson

```
public class EmergencyContactPerson
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public int Connection { get; set; }
    public string NumberPhone { get; set; }
}
```

Then data itself is successfully wrapped, but when try to send to controller the data pass, this is my ajax syntax;

```
$("#pageEmployee-input").ready(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var biodata = {}, employee = {}, emergencyContactPerson = {};
            var test = $("#formBiodata").serialize()

            $("#formBiodata").serializeArray().map(function (x) { biodata[x.name] = x.value; });
            $("#formEmployee").serializeArray().map(function (x) { employee[x.name] = x.value; });
            $("#formEmergencyContactPerson").serializeArray().map(function (x) { emergencyContactPerson[x.name] = x.value; });

            var dataFormObject = {};
            dataFormObject.Position = employee.Position
            dataFormObject.Salary = employee.Salary
            dataFormObject.Biodata = biodata
            dataFormObject.EmergencyContactPerson = emergencyContactPerson

            var dataForm = JSON.stringify(dataFormObject)
            debugger
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/Create",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });

        })
    })
```

This is when debug in controller;
[image: Debug Controller]

fixing my syntaxt or procedure

Comment: The `Gender` field is defined as `int`, but it's clearly posted as a `string`.

Comment: if one of object is has wrong type data from js are its mess up to the controller mvc ?

Comment: Controller is used to send a HTTP Request/Response.  Request has three parts 1) URI 2) HTTP Headers 3) HTTP Body.  Headers are object like Content Type and URL.  The headers have a Name followed by a colon and then the value.  You data can either be added as a custom header or in the body.  With a controller, the body data is serialized at the client and then deserialized at the server.  For JSON data a JSON serializer is used to take the c# class object and convert to JSON.  At the server the IActionResult is the deserialized body data.  The serialize and deserialize have to be complimentary.

Comment: ok guys already solved thanks Mario and jdweng

Comment: Then by all means, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure type data object on javascript is same as object on controller .net

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).